# SwiftUI: Disable/Re-Enable button based on WebView state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, wkwebview

I have a `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper around a `WebView`. I have added a bar beneath the webview with forward and back buttons. I want the buttons to be disabled when the `WebView`'s `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` properties return `false` and vice versa.

`ViewModel` includes:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  ...
   @Published var canGoBackPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
   @Published var canGoForwardPublisher = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
}
```

The `ContentView` includes:

```
struct ContentView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
   ...
   
   var body: some View {
      VStack(spacing: 0) {
         WebView(viewModel: viewModel).overlay (
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .circular)
               .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 0.5)
         )
         WebNavigationView(viewModel: viewModel)
             .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 64, maxHeight: 64)
             .background(Color.white)
      }
      
   }
```

The `WebNavigationView` (the button bar) includes:

```
struct WebNavigationView: View {
   @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
   ...      
   
   var body: some View {
      HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 64, content: {
         Button(action: goBack) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.left").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }.disabled(!viewModel.canGoBackPublisher.value).
                frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center).padding(.leading, 32)
         Button(action: goForward) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            }.disabled(!viewModel.canGoForwardPublisher.value)
                .frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center)
         Spacer()
      })
   }
   ...
```

the `WebView`'s `delegate` includes:

```
   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
      parent.viewModel.canGoBackPublisher.send(webView.canGoBack)
      parent.viewModel.canGoForwardPublisher.send(webView.canGoForward)
   }
```

The buttons start up grayed-out and disabled as expected. But they don't react to the state change, they stay disabled even when `viewModel.canGoBackPublisher.value` returns `true`. I'm a longtime iOS developer but very, very, very new to SwiftUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ending up doubling up the publisher property by defining them as @Published *and* `CurrentValueSubject`.

The easiest fix would be to just make them `Published`, which handles most of the work for you:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var canGoBack = false
   @Published var canGoForward = false
}

//...
//In delegate:
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  viewModel.canGoBack = webView.canGoBack
  viewModel.canGoForward = webView.canGoForward
}

//...
//In Navigation view:
Button(action: goBack) {
  Image(systemName: "chevron.left").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}.disabled(!viewModel.canGoBack) //<-- here
.frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center).padding(.leading, 32)

Button(action: goForward) {
  Image(systemName: "chevron.right").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
}.disabled(!viewModel.canGoForward) //<-- here
.frame(width: 24, height: 24, alignment: .center)
```

You could still define them as CurrentValueSubject if you want (and ditch the @Published property wrapper), but there's probably no need to in this case.

Good SO question on the difference between @Published and CurrentValueSubject: [Difference between CurrentValueSubject and @Published](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58676249/difference-between-currentvaluesubject-and-published)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Got lost in too many SO questions and medium articles, I think. Much obliged!!